# Better approach on getting the point on datetime just before the current datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Giving the following code where `df` is item sold table, `df1` is user point table, I want to get the user point that with datetime just before the datetime in `df` table, and the `vin` value must match

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({
                 "vin":[1,1,2,2],
                 "date":['1/1/2021 13:55','1/6/2021  13:55','1/8/2021  13:55','1/10/2021  13:55'],                
                 "quantity_sold":[1,2,3,4]})
df1=pd.DataFrame({
                 "vin":[1,1,2,2],
                 "date":['12/1/2020 12:55','1/3/2021 15:55','1/8/2021  14:55','1/10/2021  12:55'],
                 "user_point":[1,3,5,7]})



df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1['date']=pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
print(df)
print(df1)
```

Table df

```
   vin                date  quantity_sold
0    1 2021-01-01 13:55:00              1
1    1 2021-01-06 13:55:00              2
2    2 2021-01-08 13:55:00              3
3    2 2021-01-10 13:55:00              4
```

Table df1

```
   vin                date  user_point
0    1 2020-12-01 12:55:00           1
1    1 2021-01-03 15:55:00           3
2    2 2021-01-08 14:55:00           5
3    2 2021-01-10 12:55:00           7
```

expected output:

```
   vin                date  quantity_sold  user_point
0    1 2021-01-01 13:55:00              1         1.0
1    1 2021-01-06 13:55:00              2         3.0
2    2 2021-01-08 13:55:00              3         NaN
3    2 2021-01-10 13:55:00              4         7.0
```

explanation:

- for first date `2021-01-01 13:55:00`, the nearest date that happens before is `2020-12-01 12:55:00`, so it takes value `1`
- for third date `2021-01-08 13:55:00`, the nearest date that happens before is `2021-01-03 15:55:00` (but its vin 1) (date `2021-01-08 14:55:00` is vin 2 but its happening after), so it takes value `nan`

Other can reason similarly.

This is my approach, pretty ugly

```
df=pd.merge(df,df1,on="vin",how="left")
df['time_diff']=df['date_x']-df['date_y']
df.loc[df.time_diff.dt.days<0,'time_diff']=np.nan
df=df.sort_values(['vin','date_x','time_diff'])
df=df.groupby(['vin','date_x']).first().reset_index()
df.loc[df['time_diff'].isnull(),"user_point"]=np.nan
print(df[['vin','date_x','quantity_sold','user_point']].rename(columns={"date_x":"date"}))
```

Is there a more elegant approach (like `merge_asof`) to merge `df` and `df1` to product expected outcome?

Comment: Isn't the last of the user_point column supposed to be 7?

Comment: @zabop Oh yes, change it, I change the question a bit to include `vin`, without that we can use `merge_asof` to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['nearestbefore']=\
df.date.apply(lambda row: max(df1.date[df1.date < row]))
```

whichi will give you:

```
                 date  quantity_sold       nearestbefore
0 2021-01-01 13:55:00              1 2020-12-01 12:55:00
1 2021-01-06 13:55:00              2 2021-01-03 15:55:00
2 2021-01-08 13:55:00              3 2021-01-03 15:55:00
3 2021-01-10 13:55:00              4 2021-01-10 12:55:00
```

Then you can use `nearestbefore` column to merge with `df1`.

Then you can do:

```
df1.rename(columns={'date':'key'}).merge(df,on='key').drop(columns=['key'])
```

Which will give you:

```
   user_point                date  quantity_sold
0           1 2021-01-01 13:55:00              1
1           3 2021-01-06 13:55:00              2
2           3 2021-01-08 13:55:00              3
3           7 2021-01-10 13:55:00              4
```

Comment: Thanks zabop, though I have modified the question with `vin` as mentioned in the question comments earlier.

Comment: Thought about it, I think what you should do: first do the merging as described in the original question, than worry about the vins (maybe in a separate question).

Comment: IMHO, I think the reverse could be easier, merge with vin than dealt with datetime